# In the last episode of season 9, why did the Doctor need to erase this person's memory?

Tags: doctor-who

In the last episode of season 9, the Doctor said he needed to erase Clara's memory. And after Clara said that she reversed the Doctor's device, he used it anyway. Why did someone (the Doctor or Clara) have to lose their memory? And how much of the Doctor's memory was erased?

Answer (score 8):

### Because it wasn't safe for the two of them to be together any more.

The Doctor himself says (when recounting his adventures to Clara in the diner, when he doesn't know who she is):

> DOCTOR: There was only one way to keep Clara safe. I had to wipe some of her memory.
>   CLARA: Of what?
>   DOCTOR: Of me.

And later, when speaking to Ashildr at the end of the universe, he explains why (emphasis mine):

> DOCTOR: Clara's my friend.
>   ASHILDR: I know. And you're willing to risk all of Time and Space because you miss her. One wonders what the pair of you will get up to next.
>   DOCTOR: Nothing. Nothing at all. **I know I went too far. I get it. That's why I'm doing what I'm doing.**
>   ASHILDR: And what would that be?
>   DOCTOR: I'm taking her back to Earth. Somewhere safe, somewhere out of the way. **I'm going to wipe her memory of every last detail of me.**

He hoped this would enable her to escape the curse of the Raven, to become a new person rather than the Doctor-substitute she'd morphed into during her years with him, to regain her pulse and live a normal human life. But it didn't work out that way.

When Clara "reversed the polarity" of the neural block, we can assume it did exactly the same to the Doctor as it was going to do to her: it **wiped his memories *of her***. It was very selective, leaving his memories of *events* (so that he'd still be the same person even after the wipe) but making sure he'd never be able to find or recognise Clara again. Later on, in the diner, we see that he remembers a lot of what they went through together, but nothing about her personally, what she looked like or anything. The only memories he's lost are those of **Clara as a person** - he still remembers all of what they did together, and of course everything from his life before he met her.

> DOCTOR: When something goes missing, you can always recreate it by the hole it left. I know her name was Clara. I know we travelled together. I know that there was an Ice Warrior on a submarine and a mummy on the Orient Express. I know we sat together in the Cloisters and she told me something very important, but I have no idea what she said. Or what she looked like. Or how she talked. Or laughed. There's nothing there. Just nothing.

Comment: he remembers a lot of what they went through together, but nothing about her personally, what she looked like or anything. The memory wipe was very selective, leaving his memories of events (so that he'd still be the same person even after the wipe) but making sure he'd never be able to find or recognise Clara again: i dont get what memories does he still remember did he still remember does he still remember all his adventures with her as the 11th and 12th doctor from Asylum of the Daleks to Hell Bent  does he still remember all of the adventures as his past regenerations (Hartnell - Smith)

Comment: @user63430 **Yes.** See the quote at the end: he remembers travelling with Clara, meeting an ice warrior on a submarine and a mummy on the Orient Express and talking to her in the Cloisters. And of course he hasn't lost any memories from previous regenerations back to Hartnell! **The only memories he's lost are those of Clara as a person** - not of what they did together, nor of anything before he met her.

Comment: so he still  remembers  all his adventures with her as the 11th and 12th doctor from Asylum of the Daleks to Hell Bent  but only doesnt rember her face just blank on her face only the times he  just looking at her

Comment: i saw two videos called Hell Bent || Doctor's POV and Forgetting Clara Oswald - Doctor Who that made it look like the memories off  all his adventures with her as the 11th and 12th doctor from Asylum of the Daleks to Hell Bent  were erased that made me not happy check them out and tell me what you think

Comment: him still remembering all of the adventures as his past regenerations (Hartnell - Smith) after using the nerual block explains him rembering being the diner with amy and rory and recognizing river in the Christmas special right

Comment: when does the memories of all his 13 faces adventures come back after renenerating

Comment: @user63430 I didn't find the videos you mention, but evidence from the show itself is a lot more reliable than fan-made Youtube videos :-) As you say, him remembering the diner and River proves that he's retained his memories. (Anyway, it would be ridiculous if he hadn't - the show could hardly go on!) As for when he regains his memories after regenerating, it varies: Ten and Twelve spent a long time recovering from their regens, but Eleven (so I've heard - haven't watched it yet) didn't need to.

Comment: Ten and Twelve really had a long time recovering from their regens trying to remember all of the memories in his 13 faces  and eleven went back to normal and remembered everything in his past faces really quickley

Comment: @AndrewCasali Yes. In Eleven's case, this was a deliberate choice on Moffat's part. While previous newly regenerated Doctors had often taken a while to get used to their new bodies, Series 5 started with a brand-new Doctor and a brand-new Companion, and Moffat wanted to send the Eleventh Doctor straight into action saving the world rather than letting him recuperate for a while first.

Comment: when were there times when he just stands or sits an thinks about adventures or things from his past

Comment: @AndrewCasali Doesn't [my other answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/124048/31394) that we were just commenting on already have plenty of examples? In fact, so does this answer here: he remembers being with Amy and Rory in the diner, with Clara on the Orient Express, and so on. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: what did you mean by The only memories he's lost are those of Clara as a person - not of what they did together, nor of anything before he met her an also in the diner we see that he remembers a lot of what they went through together, but nothing about her personally, what she looked like or anything. The only memories he's lost are those of Clara as a person - he still remembers all of what they did together, and of course everything from his life before he met her.

Comment: @AndrewCasali We talked about this before, in comments up above. The quote at the end of this answer also makes it quite clear. **The Doctor knows he was with someone called Clara all that time, but not what she looked like or how she behaved.** He doesn't remember what *she* was like as a person, but he does remember everything they did together, and all his memories from before he met her are intact.

Comment: how can he still remember all his adventures with clara  as the 11th and 12th doctor from Asylum of the Daleks to Hell Bent and still remembers all of his past adventures as William Hartnell, Patrick Troughton, Jon Pertwee, Tom Baker, Peter Davison, Colin Baker, Sylvester McCoy, Paul McGann, John Hurt Christopher Eccleston, David Tennant, Matt Smith if  he used a neural block that erases memories that made im fell to the floor in the tardis an dhe said clara who

Comment: @AndrewCasali Because **it only erased his memories of Clara**. Those were the only memories the neural block erased. It didn't erase his memories of his adventures with her, nor of his life before he met her, because that's not how it worked. (Also, you don't have to keep listing all the actors who played the Doctor. I do know what his past regenerations are.)

Comment: good point put he said before he did it I'm going to wipe her memory of every last detail of me. It'll be like our friendship never happened. It won't hurt, it'll be nothing. You'll just pass out for a moment. When you wake, you'll be fine. When you wake up, you will have forgotten me. You'll have forgotten we ever even met. 
: Because it's the only way. That stuff in your head, the image of me, they could use it to find you. so does that mean it erased all his adventures with clara as the 11th and 12th doctor from Asylum of the Daleks to Hell Bent

Comment: @AndrewCasali Perhaps a little inconsistency there? Or perhaps Clara's "reversing the polarity" didn't *exactly* work, so its effect on her was slightly different from its effect on him. Or perhaps it's natural that it worked differently on him from how it would have done on her, since things like Ice Warriors and mummies on the Orient Express have always been everyday events for him but weren't for her until she started travelling with him.

Comment: This answer is quite correct…but I wonder at the effectiveness of the neural block, then. If he doesn’t remember Clara at all, but he remembers dealing with Zygon extremists with *someone* and UNIT, couldn’t he just go back and ask UNIT about her? And so forth with the numerous other people he remembers being present for their adventures. And wouldn’t the same thing work for Clara (though it might be a bit more difficult for her)?

Comment: Indeed, by *Class*, he seems to at least know her last name and where she worked, which is fairly consistent with the idea that he was able to find out who she was.

Comment: @Adamant I suspect the explanation is something wibbly-wobbly. Same when they got rid of Amy and Rory: even if the Doctor couldn't go back to New York to find them, couldn't he park the TARDIS somewhere else and get to Manhattan on that motorbike of his? Things made so much more sense in the RTD era ... *sigh* ...

Answer (score 7):

He explains this in the episode itself:

> **Doctor:** When you wake up, you will have forgotten me. You'll have forgotten we ever even met.
>
> **Clara:** And why would I want that?
>
> **Doctor:** Because it's the only way. That stuff in your head, the image of me, they could use it to find you.
>
> <sup>*Doctor Who* Series 9 Episode 12: "Hell Bent"</sup>

However, the fact that he's willing to make the compromise (to potentially erase his own memory instead of hers) hints at the real reason: he and Clara are basically perfect for each other, and are *incredibly* dangerous for it. He gives this answer a little later on, as well:

> **Doctor:** You and me together. Look how far I went, for fear of losing you. This has to stop. One of us has to go.
>
> *[...]*
>
> **Doctor:**  It's okay. It's okay. I went too far. I broke all my own rules. I became the Hybrid. This is right. I accept it.
>
> <sup>*Doctor Who* Series 9 Episode 12: "Hell Bent"</sup>

Which ties nicely to a comment made earlier by Ashildir/Me:

> **Me:**  What if the Hybrid wasn't one person, but two?
>
> **Doctor:** Two?
>
> **Me:** A dangerous combination of a passionate and powerful Time Lord and a young woman so very similar to him. Companions who are willing to push each other to extremes.
>
> **Doctor:** She's my friend. She's just my friend.
>
> *[...]*
>
> **Me:** I know. And you're willing to risk all of time and space because you miss her. One wonders what the pair of you will get up to next.
>
> <sup>*Doctor Who* Series 9 Episode 12: "Hell Bent"</sup>

Comment: I think the quotes I found are better :-) What he says to Clara herself isn't as reliable as what he says when he thinks she can't hear him. Congrats on the 18-second ninja though (because I was typing up a longer answer)!

Comment: @randal'thor Perhaps, but the expressed sentiment is the same (the bad lie notwithstanding)

Comment: IMO, the " they could use it to find you" bit isn't entirely a lie. He really does want to protect her, and she'll never be completely safe or completely human as long as she has those memories in her head. (See the paragraph just below the quotes in my answer.)

Comment: @randal'thor It's probably true, but there's no sensible way it can be his  reason. If that was really the reason, the compromise he agrees to (whether it was genuine or not; there is a theory that he still remembers Clara, and was lying about everything) is totally nonsensical