# What memories did the neural block let the Doctor keep and which did he forget does he stiil remember the adventures in his past regenrations

Tags: doctor-who

In "Hell Bent," when he was talking to Clara in the diner, he said he remembers her name is Clara, and he knows they traveled together; he remembers ice warriors in a submarine and the mummy on the express and remembers being in the cloisters, but he doesn't remember the message she said or how she talked or looks like.

It made me think the neural block wiped the Doctor's memories of Clara, but does he still remember his adventures with her as the 11th and 12th doctor from *Asylum of the Daleks* to *Hell Bent* and does he still remember the adventures as his past regenerations (Hartnell - Smith)?

Comment: I believe I've already answered this [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114017/season-9-episode-12-why-did-the-doctor-need-to-erase-this-persons-memory/114023#114023) (that question asks the same thing as yours and also why the memory-wipe happened).