# When does Class take place relative to the Doctor Who timeline?

Tags: doctor-who, class

*Class* is a spin-off series of *Doctor Who*, following the students at Coal Hill School, where Clara Oswald taught (among other significant *Doctor Who* events). Now, we know the first episode must have happened after Season 9 of *Doctor Who*, since

> the Doctor gazes sadly at a plaque bearing the name C. Oswald.

How long afterward, though? And where does it appear relative to the next season, or to “The Husbands of River Song”?  In short, what is its place in the *Doctor Who* timeline?

Comment: Speculation but, within the world timeline, we assume Class is set present-day (2016). Although this is not stated anywhere in-show as of yet, the clothing, technology etc would back this up. In terms of within the Doctor's personal timeline, we know very little AT PRESENT. Just that it is within Capaldi's reign, and after Clara's "death" judging by his reaction upon seeing her name (below Danny Pink). We also know that it is the season 9 TARDIS interior, as glimpsed through the open door. Beyond this, however, is unknown at present.

Comment: Somewhere along the Wibbly Wobbly Timey Wimey line.

Comment: @sequoiad, "judging by [The Doctor's] reaction upon seeing her name": Oy! Sloppy writing!!! The Doctor is not supposed to remember Clara's name or who she was. Is anybody even trying anymore to stay consistent? (I didn't see it; I didn't even know about the show until this question)

Comment: @EuroMicelli - Actually, he would have known by that point. Don’t forget, he could remember everything they did together, just not Clara herself. He knew her name, thanks at least to the person who found him in Nevada. The neural block only worked on him. He could just ask UNIT, among myriad other groups.

Comment: @EuroMicelli - `When something goes missing, you can always recreate it by the hole it left. I know her name was Clara. I know we travelled together. I know that there was an Ice Warrior on a submarine and a mummy on the Orient Express. I know we sat together in the Cloisters.` If he wanted a picture and background information on Clara, it would have been easy enough. Besides, after the diner scene, he clearly knew what Clara looked like. Her face was painted all over his TARDIS.

Comment: I disagree with that assessment of the consequences of "Hell Bent", but that's off-topic for this question

Comment: @EuroMicelli - The script *is* pretty clear about what he forgot. [This question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/121425/51379) (well, its dupe) asks basically the same thing. Whether that renders the ending less poignant is another matter, of course.

Comment: Also, he has his new Sonic Screwdriver. Presumably, it fits in the Doctor's timeline where it fits in the production timeline - after last season of DW, & before the next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He has the new screwdriver so it's after "Hell Bent", but he doesn't have Nardole yet (unless he's just sitting in the TARDIS), and if that were the case then how come the Doctor’s not guarding the vault, anyway? So it's before "The Husbands of River Song".

Timeline:

1. Hell Bent
2. Class
3. Husbands of River Song
4. Return of Doctor Mysterio