# How does the 12th Doctor remember all the adventures of his first regeneration cycle?

Tags: doctor-who

The 11th Doctor (Matt Smith), which was the last of his regenerative cycle, gets a new one on Trenzelore. Then he changes to the 12th Doctor (Peter Capaldi), but he still remembers all his adventures in his first cycle. How does the 12th Doctor remember all of the adventures in his first cycle (his past 13 incarnations)?

Comment: That's just how [regeneration](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Regeneration) works; his ability to regenerate had basically been used up, and it was restored by the Time Lords.. but that didn't change the fundamental nature of how regeneration works.  Think of it as recharging his batteries, not rebooting his existence.

Comment: i dont get it what you mean how can he still remember all of his 13 faces adventures hartnell to smith if 12th capaldi is the first in a new regenerative cycle

Comment: Because it's still the same person; regeneration causes massive physical changes (and even some mental ones), but it's the same being.  The new regenerative cycle was just a refilling of his reserves, basically -- it didn't change who he was.

Comment: what about the master he used up his lives hes been stelling bodies became a snake resurrected  died became a horror show and became missy how does he still remember all of his adventures as Roger Delgado (1971–73) Peter Pratt (1976) Geoffrey Beevers (1981) Anthony Ainley (1981–89) Eric Roberts (1996) Derek Jacobi (2007) John Simm (2007–10) Michelle Gomez (2014–present)

Comment: @K-H-W: It sounds like you have the answer.

Comment: how is it a duplicate

Comment: Flagging for a duplicate is a confusing term; it's not saying that the questions are the same, but that the answer to one also answers the other.  In this case, the Doctor's memory was not reset (other than the normal post-regeneration fuzz) after the Capaldi regeneration occurred.  Basically, granting him 'another cycle of regenerations' just refilled his regeneration batteries -- no other significant change seems to have occured.  (Although the episode 'Hell Bent' makes the point that it's unknown how many more times he can now regenerate.)

Comment: Not a duplicate: Other question is asking about a specific Doctor's observed symptoms immediately post-regeneration. This question is asking how do Doctors (or Time Lords) manage to retain their memories when they regenerate. Very different. Furthermore, the other answers *barely answer the question they're for*, with nothing to back them up to boot.

Comment: “How does the 12th Doctor remember all of the adventures in his first cycle (his past 13 incarnations)?” — Why would he *not* remember them?

Comment: @CreationEdge I agree this isn't a duplicate. But re. the answers to the other question, [check again](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/124048/31394) :-)

Comment: He's been watching the shows? ;-)

Answer (score 7):

### Why shouldn't he?

Giving him a new set of regenerations isn't like giving him a completely new person to turn into (or at least, no more so than regeneration is *always* turning into a new person).

Think of it like **recharging his batteries**. He was given a certain amount of 'charge' (regenerations) at the beginning, and when he'd used them all up, it would be time to die. Eventually he was on the very last one, about to die, when suddenly the Time Lords gave him a whole new set of regenerations, refilling his 'battery'. He's still the same person, with the same thoughts and memories, but with some new 'charge' in him.

Or, better, think of it as **gaining new lives in a computer game**. You've been playing for a long time, and lost several lives; you're on your very last chance. Then you achieve some goal or unlock some new level, and you're given a bunch more lives as a reward. **You're not restarting the game; you're just continuing on with more chances, and with all the points you've earned so far intact.**

Since he was at the end of his life, he promptly used up one of the new regenerations, giving him a new face as well as a new set of regenerations. But he could just as easily have been given them at an earlier stage in his life, in which case he would have gone on as Matt Smith until that regeneration ran out and only *then* started to use his new regenerations.

Comment: More than goals, or something unlocked for a new set of lives, I think he used a cheat code :P